# Dlib not using CUDA but have process

Tags: python, python-3.x, dlib

I install Dlib with this commands:

```
$ workon <your env name here> # optional
$ git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git
$ cd dlib
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake .. -DDLIB_USE_CUDA=1 -DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=1
$ cmake --build .
$ cd ..
$ python setup.py install
```

After everything was finish to install, i try to run this code:

```
print(cuda.get_num_devices())
v = dlib.DLIB_USE_CUDA
```

The print give me result of `1`
but `v` is `False`

Any idea what can be the problem?

I'm using this graphical card:

```
Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
```

**EDIT**
I now found out this in the compile:

```
-- Found Threads: TRUE
CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
-- Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "7.5")
-- DID NOT FIND CUDA
-- Disabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL NOT USE CUDA
```

Any idea what is missing and need to be install? I can see that the required `CUDA` is `7.5`, but from the `Nvidia` documentation my card support `6.1`, So i will not able to use dlib with cuda?

Comment: while compiling, cmake will output some messages saying dlib is using CUDA. Did you get them?

Comment: @timedacorn I update my question with edit

Comment: it seems you dont have cuda installed.try installing cuda and then install dlib.

Comment: @timedacorn and what about the cuda version?

Comment: install cuda 10. i dont think dlib has added support for cuda 10.2. so install cuda 10 and then dlib.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install CUDA toolkit and also Cudnn

https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#install-windows